# Why and how does DynamoDB allows consuming more than allotted RCUs in Scan Operation?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

While doing a tutorial, i bulk loaded data to my dynamoDB `JobsApplication` table with around 400 random jobs posts.

[image: Here is how the table looks]

Using `Node.js` and `aws-sdk` i performed a scan operation.

```js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1'
});
var print = require('./../lib/helpers').printPretty;
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var epochNow = 1506043477;

var params = {
  "TableName": "GMJS.Job",
  "FilterExpression": "CountryId = :country AND ClosingTime > :time",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":country": {
      "S": "18"
    },
    ":time": {
      "N": epochNow.toString()
    }
  },
  "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "TOTAL"
};

dynamodb.scan(params).promise()
  .then(print)
  .catch(print);
```

My table currently has 5 RCUs and WCUs assigned to it. The scan operation gave a result in less than 2 seconds and apart from results showed this info:

```js
"Count": 7,
    "ScannedCount": 100,
    "ConsumedCapacity": {
        "TableName": "GMJS.Job",
        "CapacityUnits": 89.5
    }
}
Size of data: 50.8 KB
```

I have turned off auto scaling. So how did it consumed 89.5 `RCUs` in 2 seconds when i had only allotted 5 `RCUs` to the table? If it had to consume 89.5 `RCUs` it could have used 5 `RCUs` per second for 17.9 seconds and then returned the result or it could have said the table requires more `RCUs` for such an expensive scanning operation etc.

So how did it used 89.5 `RCUs` to scan when i only allotted 5 `RCUs` is my main question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DynamoDB has a certain amount of burst capability that can be put to use when needed:

> DynamoDB provides some flexibility in the per-partition throughput
>   provisioning. When you are not fully utilizing a partition's
>   throughput, DynamoDB retains a portion of your unused capacity for
>   later bursts of throughput usage.  DynamoDB currently retains up to
>   five minutes (300 seconds) of unused read and write capacity.  During
>   an occasional burst of read or write activity, these extra capacity
>   units can be consumed very quickly—even faster than the per-second
>   provisioned throughput capacity that you've defined for your table.
>   However, do not design your application so that it depends on burst
>   capacity being available at all times: DynamoDB can and does use burst
>   capacity for background maintenance and other tasks without prior
>   notice.
>
> **Note**
>
> In the future, these details of burst capacity may change.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Bursting

Comment: I think, what we really want to know is, what if auto-scaling is disabled and you exceed the burst. Would DynamoDB start throwing an error ?